# stuck with uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

when using `.rules()` in JQuery, I searched, and most of the problems solved by using setTimeout, but in my case, it didn't work.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "Value", "Text"),
    htmlAttributes: new
    {
         @readonly = Model.IsReadonly,
         @class = "form-control location select-search",
         data_val_required = string.Format(this.GCUResources("IsRequired"), this.GCUResources("Country")),
         data_placeholder = this.GCUResources("Country")
    })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "field-validation-valid validationspan validation-error-label" })
```

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#CountryId").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Some Text"
        }
    });
}, 0);
```

I also tried to use the validate before adding the rule

```
$("form").validate();
```

Comment: May you add the HTML? Your current code is not a [mcve], so we are left guessing what the issue is.

Comment: Where is your `.rules()` code?  Is it in document ready?  Is it in the `<head>` or just before the `</body>` line?  Did you try with a (substantially) longer setTimeout, eg 5000?

Comment: Have you actually instantiated the jQuery validate library on the form *before* you try and add the rules?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the HTML is generated by the `@Html`

Comment: @freedomn-m that solved my problem , many thanks

Comment: Which was it?  longer timeout just means the code is probably in the wrong place

Comment: What framework are you using to generate the HTML (please tag as appropriate). The problem is most likely caused because you try to apply `.rules()` to an element that has not been generated - that's why setting a timeout solves the problem, but the proper way to do it would be to check if the element exists, then apply `rules()` to it. Most frameworks set off some kind of event when an element is generated, you might want to look for that.

Comment: the rule is executed before the Jquery validate is rendered, so i got this problem .
thanks all for helping me

Comment: @SwimmerF *"A tag is a word or phrase that describes the **topic of the question**"* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) - this question is about jquery validation, not about MVC. Ideally, they should have provided the HTML *as rendered* rather than the source, but it should not be added as a tag as that's not what the question is related to. (the rest of your comment is highly relevant) –